# Codeigniter 4 Modules not working properly

Tags: codeigniter, module, hmvc

I have been trying to setup codeigniter 4 modules but it seems something is not working properly 
it takes me to 404 or not found.

i have gone through this doc : https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/general/modules.html?highlight=modules

I have simply installed Ci4 and follow this doc did not tweaked anything else as we do in previous ci 3 hmvc practice.

Is there anything else beside autoload ? 
I'm basic php dev. please guide.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add enough code to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

As DFriend indicates, it's difficult to know what the issue could be based on the minimal information provided.

That said one difference between CI3 and CI4 that I noticed is the location of the base index.php, which in CI4 is located within the "public" directory. So, assuming you are using Apache, you need to adjust it's default directory to include public.

_t